# Is there a way to get the Suggested Contacts through Outlook API?

Tags: rest, outlook, outlook-api

I'm currently developing an app that fetches my contacts in my Microsoft account.
The problem is, unlike Google, when I send or receive an email to/from a new contact, it isn't copied into My Contacts, so I can't get it through `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts`.

However, when I wrote a new email, it appears as a suggestion, so I guess it is stored somewhere else.

The question is: is there a way to access to my `suggested contacts` through the API to get their emails? And how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is only available in beta version for now, please see the following api:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/contacts?$select=EmailAddresses,GivenName,Surname,DisplayName
```

This api will return all the contacts that you have received an email from or sent an email to :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked with the beta API. I even don't need to use `$select`.
Be careful, if someone wants to use your link, you forgot the `?` between `contacts` and `$select` 

Comment: @bjorge Thanks for the correction. I am happy it worked for you!

Comment: The change in behavior in the beta version of the Contacts API is due to a change in how the API processes a request to the `/me/contacts` endpoint, and is under review. Keep in mind this is a beta so this may not be how the API ends up acting in stable versions.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you're looking for is the [People API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/people-rest-operations). As that page says:

> The People API returns relevent person entities with each request. A person aggregates information from across mail, contacts and social networks. The results are ordered by their relevance, which is determined by the criteria specified in the request and ranked based on multiple communication, collaboration and business relationships.

Comment: Thanks Jason :) I didn't know about people api. Contacts beta version was my workaround.