# Find all the contacts I sent an email to via Outlook Rest API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get all the contacts I sent a email (or responded to) via Outlook Contacts Rest API.

The default Outlook contact API only gives me contacts that I created in my contact manager. But I found "[Is there a way to get the Suggested Contacts through Outlook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690854/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-suggested-contacts-through-outlook-api/46713298#46713298)" and sure enough, it gives me all "suggested" contacts (i.e. any contact I ever received an email from or sent an email to).

- is this really the way to do it? No way in the "classic" API?
- any way to find all the contacts I talked to (i.e. I wrote an email to?). That's the way Google handles "suggested contact" through their API, and not every contact I ever received an email from, spam included.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you're looking for is the [People API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/people-rest-operations). As that page says:

> The People API returns relevent person entities with each request. A person aggregates information from across mail, contacts and social networks. The results are ordered by their relevance, which is determined by the criteria specified in the request and ranked based on multiple communication, collaboration and business relationships.

The change in behavior in the beta version of the Contacts API is due to a change in how the API processes a request to the `/me/contacts` endpoint, and is under review. Keep in mind this is a beta so this may not be how the API ends up acting in stable versions.